# Python libraries in Dockerfile for Node.js Project

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, awsdeploy

I am trying to upload my Node.js project to Docker Platform on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I am running into problems adding python libraries in Dockerfile.
With this file deployment is fine:

```
FROM node:8.16
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./
RUN npm cache clean --force && npm install
COPY . /opt/app
ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

But once I add Python libraries for Docker file:

```
FROM node:8.16
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./
RUN npm cache clean --force && npm install
COPY . /opt/app

FROM python:3.7    
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY . /tmp/

ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I get an error while deploying:

> Failed to run Docker container: a46e6adbe0fee8d3 docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"npm\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.. Check snapshot logs for details.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docker reference for FROM](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from), while having multiple FROM instructions in a single Dockerfile is allowed:

> Each FROM instruction clears any state created by previous instructions.

If you are looking to build your application on top of an environment containing both node.js and python 3, I suggest you look around docker hub.  Perhaps [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/nikolaik/python-nodejs/) will help.